# not able to send cc using controller in laravel

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

i have form in laravel, when the user submits the form, data goes to database and my email. its working properly. now i want one copy or successful message to go to that particlar user who submits it. i tried the following in my controller:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Register;
use App\Mail\SendEmail;
use Session;
use Mail;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class RegController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        //
    }


    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

       // return $request;


// return $request->Fee;
            $data = new Register;
            $data->firstname = $request->firstname;
            $data->lastname = $request->lastname;
            $data->mobilenumber = $request->mobilenumber;
            $data->experience = $request->experience;
            $data->designation = $request->designation;
            $data->confirmation = $request->confirmation;
            $data->company = $request->company;
            $data->address = $request->address;
            $data->addressline2 = $request->addressline2;
            $data->city = $request->city;
            $data->state = $request->state;
            $data->pin = $request->pin;
            $data->country = $request->country;
            $data->Whatsapp = $request->Whatsapp;
            $data->alternatenumber = $request->alternatenumber;
            $data->Email = $request->Email;
            $data->CompanyRegNumber = $request->CompanyRegNumber;
            $data->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp = $request->Date_Incorporation_orBusi_Stp;
            $data->GSTIN = $request->GSTIN;
            $data->Services_Offered = $request->Services_Offered;
            $data->Annual_Turnover = $request->Annual_Turnover;
            $data->Declaration = $request->Declaration;
            $data->Fee = $request->Fee;

            $data->termsandconditions = $request->termsandconditions;
            // $data->Fee = $request->Fee;
            $data->Mode_of_Payment = $request->Mode_of_Payment;

            $data->Recommended_by_A = $request->Recommended_by_A;
            $data->Recommended_by_B = $request->Recommended_by_B;




 if($request->hasFile('Photo')) {
      $image = $request->file('Photo');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Photo');

     Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Photo=$filename;
    }
 if($request->hasFile('Receipt')) {
      $image = $request->file('Receipt');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Receipt');
    Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Receipt=$filename;
    }
 if($request->hasFile('Signature')) {
      $image = $request->file('Signature');
      $filename = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path('uploads/Signature');
      Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,  File::get($image));
      $data->Signature=$filename;
    }

            $data->save();
            Session::flash('registered','reg');


        $name = $request->firstname." ".$request->lastname;
        $subject = "TEIA";
        $message =  $data->id;

         $photo = $data->Photo;
         $sign = $data->Signature;
         $recipt= $data->Receipt;
         $email = 'teiamembers@gmail.com';



         
      Mail::to($email)
      ->cc(['$reg->Email')
      ->send( new SendEmail($subject,$message , $photo ,$sign,$recipt));


                  //
                  // return redirect('demo')->with(['reg'=>$data]);

            return redirect('formdata');
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

but its not working. can anyone tell me how to correctly send cc?

Comment: `->cc(['$reg->Email')` it's a typo? or this is your actual code? what is the error you are getting here?

Comment: where the `$reg` variable comes from?

Comment: @hassan in my sendmail.php i used {{$reg->Email}} to display email to the browser.. actually my form html is <input type="text" name="email"/>...

Comment: @hassan what should i actually use there to retreive the email field

Comment: I think that you need to `->cc($request->Email)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cc` email address looks to be incorrect. It should be:

```
...
->cc($request->email)
...
```

`email` is the name of your html form input element. Change it accordingly.

*It is good practice to send emails via queue in order to achieve better user experience.*